# deezer playlist without user object for playlist collaborative

Tags: playlist, deezer

I want to create a jukebox collaborativewith the api deezer.
But for that's, i want to create a playlist who everyboy can add a music on this playlist.
Do you have idea ?

Thks

Answer (score 3):

Your playlist will always be linked to a Deezer user, there's no way to do otherwise:

1. you create a collaborative playlist:
   http://developers.deezer.com/api/user/playlists doing a POST request
   to api.deezer.com/user/your_user_id/playlists
2. Change this playlist to be collaborative:
   http://developers.deezer.com/api/playlist#actions doing a POST request to
   api.deezer.com/playlist/your_playlist_id
3. Add tracks to the playlist
   http://developers.deezer.com/api/playlist/tracks doing a POST
   request on api.deezer.com/playlist/your_playlist_id/tracks

Comment: Ok thanks but if i want to create a playlist whitout user id, it's possible ?

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible... You could create a fake user (named with your app name though)